# MIPS immediate instructions ori/addi/lui etc require Register Write?

Tags: computer-science, mips, cpu-architecture

I am learning about pipelining in MIPS. I had a question about immediate instructions and their instruction process. I keep reading that ori/addi/lui and are immediate instructions or I-type. I also keep finding that I-type instructions only require the first three stages of the of a MIPS 5-stage process. Like shown below

```
     |instruction memory|register read|ALU op|DataMemory|Register Write|
     |------------------------------------------------------------------
 addi|         X        |       X     |    X |          |              |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 ori |         X        |       X     |    X |          |              |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 lui |         X        |       X     |   X  |          |              |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is first, is this table correct? I find it weird that these instructions do not require a register write to change the contents of the register. If this table is not right can someone help me with what the right table would look like?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate instructions of `addi/ori/lui` and so on do need to write their results to the register file. For example: `addi $dest, $src, immd_val`. For this instruction, one of the operands is an immediate value. So the computation will be, `$dest = $src + immd_val`. As you can see the result has to be written back to register `$dest`. You are on the right track, you need to modify your table suitably.

There are some instructions that do not need to write-back the result to the register file like the branch, store, compare etc.